# No route matches [DELETE] "/articles" in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using Rails 5.2.0 and just trying to create a simple blog with all of the CRUD functions. I can create/edit posts however I am unable to Delete them. The error message I am getting:

```
No route matches [DELETE] "/articles"
```

I have the `resources :articles` command in my routes.rb

ArticlesController

```
  def destroy
@article = Article.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url notice: 'Article was successfully deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
```

Show page link:

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(@article), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure"} %>
```

Comment: Your code is correct. It shouldn't be generating '/articles' at all, it should have generated `/articles/:id`. Try rails server restart maybe? Can you also post the output from `rake routes`

Answer (score 3):

Look, I think you have missed the object like if your `delete` link into the `each` loop then definitely it has an object like `@articles.each do |article|` that means the object name is `article` so on the delete link you need to pass the object like this

```
<%= link_to 'Delete', article_path(article), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure"} %>
```

`@article` to `article`, please refactor the code.

and update the `destroy` method like this

```
def destroy
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to articles_url notice: 'Article was successfully deleted.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```

If it is not helpful to you, then please copy & paste your error logs here from the log file.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Run `rails routes`.

Your `destroy route` might be like this:

```
 DELETE     /articles/:id(.:format)
```

*You have to specify the id you want to be destroyed!

Comment: you don't have to specify the id, he has used `article_path(@article)` helper which is perfectly valid

Comment: Yes I was about to editing my answer. The path is not defined they should probably define a path for destroy method so that the can use the article_path helper!

Comment: My destroy route is as exactly as you said. But i don't think that that is the reason since i have the "@article = Article.find(params[:id])" in my Destroy action.

Comment: Do you have a defined path like this ? article_path(@article)

Comment: Yes.

{article GET    /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                  articles#show
                          PATCH  /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                  articles#update
                          PUT    /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                  articles#update
                          DELETE /articles/:id(.:format)                                                                  articles#destroy}

Comment: what is ur rails version ? 
did you restart your server after defining the route ? 
your code is correct .

Comment: Yes I restarted everything. I am on Rails 5.2.0. I generated the app using the Scaffold generator.

Comment: @j_nguyen that's weird. that route cannot generate '/articles' at all. Are you sure you are clicking the right delete link in page and saved the code correctly/

Comment: maybe your @article is empty or something !

Answer (score 0):

[A Tour of Rails’ jQuery UJS](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/a-tour-of-rails-jquery-ujs)
Make sure **Jquery** files are loaded properly in your rails project. Read the above link for more information.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id]
  @article.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to articles_url}
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```